# Continuity of a function where part of the domain is a singleton

Tags: calculus

Let $f:(-\infty,1)\cup\{2\}\cup(3,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function defined as
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0&,\ x \in (-\infty, 1) \\
\frac{1}{2}&,\ x \in \{2\} \\
1&,\ x \in (3, \infty)
\end{cases}$$
Is the function continuous?

My instinct was no, just going by a visualization of the function's graph. But the more I think about it, the more I suspect it may actually be continuous.

Comment: The function is continuous in each point *of it's domain*, so it's continuous.

Comment: What IS the definition of continuous you know?

Comment: Do not think or suspect or rely on instinct. Try the definition. E.g., with the $\epsilon\delta$ definition, you can always use $\delta=1$.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen I would say that that _is_ a very intuitive explanation why $f$ is continuous. Continuity means "If $x$ is close to 2, then $f(x)$ should be close to $f(2)$". However, since there are no $x$ close to $2$ in the domain, continuity holds.